# Why do we need to wrap test functions in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I was studying `unittest` by following the examples [here](https://youtu.be/6tNS--WetLI).

In the following code, `def test_add()` is supposed to be wrapped in `class testClass()`, but for my curiosity, I didn't encapsulate it.

```
# class testClass(unittest.TestCase):

def test_add(self):
    result = cal_fun.add_fuc(5, 10)
    self.assertEqual(result, 15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The result came out in VScode as:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why was no test run? Why must the `def test_add()` be wrapped in a `class`?

Comment: See [Organizing Test Code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) section of unittest docs. Because unittest discovery looks for TestCases. See [load_tests protocol section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) if you want customized behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expansion on [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866873/testing-functions-in-a-wrapped-class-in-python#comment116456641_65866873).

The unittest module has a [Test Discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) feature/function. When you run it on a directory, it looks for pre-defined structures, definitions, and patterns. Namely:

> In order to be compatible with test discovery, all of the test files must be [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#tut-modules) or [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#tut-packages) (including [namespace packages](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-namespace-package)) importable from the top-level directory of the project (this means that their filenames must be valid [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)).

> The basic building blocks of unit testing are *test cases* — single scenarios that must be set up and checked for correctness. In unittest, test cases are represented by [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) instances. To make your own test cases you must write subclasses of [`TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) or use [`FunctionTestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.FunctionTestCase).

The relevant answer to your question is that test functions must be wrapped in a `TestCase`. Not simply wrapped in just some "`class testClass()`" as you said, but the class must specifically inherit from `unittest.TestCase`. In addition, that `assertEqual` method is only available as part of a `TestCase`, because it's [a method of the `TestCase` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual). If you somehow got that code of yours to run, `self.assertEqual` would result in an error. You would have to use plain `assert`'s.

To go into more detail, you will have to read the section on unittest's [load_tests Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) and specifically the [`loadTestsFromModule(module, pattern=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule) method:

> Return a suite of all test cases contained in the given module. This method searches *module* for classes derived from [`TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) and creates an instance of the class for each test method defined for the class.

Finally, it's not just about wrapping your test functions in a `unittest.TestCase` class, your tests must follow some pre-defined patterns:

- By default, unittest looks for files matching the pattern `test*.py`. This is done by the [discover(start_dir, pattern='test*.py', top_level_dir=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) method of `unittest`'s [TestLoader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) class, which is "*used to create test suites from classes and modules*".
- By default, unittest looks for methods that start with `test` (ex. `test_function`). This is done by the [testMethodPrefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.testMethodPrefix) attribute of `unittest`'s [TestLoader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) class, which is a "*string giving the prefix of method names which will be interpreted as test methods. The default value is 'test'.*"

If you want some customized behavior, you'll have to override the `load_tests` protocol.